# Can I get all EditText of an android layout at once?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Can I get all EditText of android layouts along with there ids,values on a click event or on load so that I can update text dynamically.
Thanks In Advance.

Edited -
I am using dynamic form generator script from here
http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/04/android-form-generator/
Which works fine....it has a default option so i can set default value too.
What I wanna do it to change its fields value through code once it is loaded.
But i can not understand how to select those fields.
So asking how can get all editText with there ID from a form.

Comment: Please clarify the question. Include code and the specific problem with it.

Comment: please check my question just edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using ViewGroup

```
 ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.your_group);
for (int i = 0, count = group.getChildCount(); i < count; ++i) {
    View view = group.getChildAt(i);
    if (view instanceof EditText) {
        ((EditText)view).setText("");//here it will be clear all the EditText field
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through parent view to get all EditTexts.

```
ViewGroup parentView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
for(int i=0; i < parentView.getChildCount(); i++) {
View childView = parentView.getChildAt(i);
int resID = childView.getId();
// childView.getText().toString(); etc
}
```

Comment: You should define this recursively and check if each child is `instanceof ViewGroup` so that you can get EditTexts on all levels.